# How to display a text who is displayed in the console, in my TextArea?

Tags: java, swing, class, jtextarea, settext

As part of our second semester project, we have to create an escape game in Java.

We have managed to display our text in the console, however, we cannot display the same text in our window (which is in another class).
We know that we have to use setText() since it is a TextArea, but we don't know how to do it.

```
private JTextArea texte;

private JButton button;

private JProgressBar bar;

public IHM() {
        this.window = new JFrame("Esc'App Game");

        this.window.setContentPane(this.panelCreation());

        this.window.pack();
        this.window.setVisible(true);

    }

public JPanel panelCreation() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        this.texte = new JTextArea("Erreur affichage de texte");

        texte.setText(""); // <- here 

        panel.add(texte);
        texte.getText();

        this.window.add(panel);

        return panel;
    }
```

And our main :

```
// Ask for the pseudo
Player p1 = new Player();
System.out.println(p1.getPseudo());

// change System.out to setText() ?

// Ask for the theme
Player.getTheme();

// Creation of a new Theme
Theme t1 = new Theme(Player.myTheme);
```

for the moment, we don't have any result or any error message because we don't have any idea.

Comment: instead of doing : System.out.println(...), do something like: myTextField.setText(...)

Comment: As you mention that it's another class, you may consider putting your text area as public field instead of private. This way you'll be able to access through yourClass.texte.setText("...");
However, the best will be to create some get/set accessors to this field.

Comment: @AntonioCalvente terrible suggestion. he would better add a method, so he doesn't give full access to his textfield to classes that shouldn't have it

Comment: @Stultuske That's why I added the "however" part to avoid public access :) It's still a school project, better to start with something working and then improve it IMO (and also that's why I put it as a comment instead of answer)

Comment: @AntonioCalvente I've already try to do this method (yourClass.texte.setText("...")) but it don't works in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

You could start reading the official Oracle tutorials on [Swing text components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

There you will find that a `JTextArea` has methods `setText()` and `getText()` for example. And to be ready to do something really useful, you probably want to study how to use [models](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) for your components.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public void println(String s) {
    try {
        int end = text.getDocument().getLength();
        text.getDocument().insertString(end, s + "\n", null);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

UPDATE

```
public void println(String s) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> {
        try {
            int end = text.getDocument().getLength();
            text.getDocument().insertString(end, s + "\n", null);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it's a little bit hard for me i think but thanks :)

Comment: It's not that hard. What do you find hard?

Comment: some lines, we have seen try and catch in class but the code between like : ` text.getDocument().getLength();
        text.getDocument().insertString(end, s + "\n", null);` is a bit hard to adapt and to understand for our project

Comment: @ma26lle 1) declare method `println` in your `IHM` class, 2) make sure you have access to an instance of `IHM` from your `main`, 3) replace `System.out.println(p1.getPseudo());` with `ihm.println(p1.getPseudo());`.

Comment: @ma26lle actually you're right: it could be slightly more complicated if the thread executing this is not the event dispatch thread. See my update